# Get distance between point and curve in image

Tags: python, image, distance

I'm fairly new to programming and I'm really strugling with a problem, not knowing how to solve it.
I have an abacus, with several curves, I don't have the equations of the curve, just the image (https://prnt.sc/1tcoa0p).
For a given point (x,y) I need to get the value of the curve (or an approximate value if it's inbetween curves).
I'm thinking my best bet is with Python, but I have no idea on how to achieve it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Perhaps the easiest way is to label 10..20 points on the curves and approximate the 2d function. Working with image will be a lot more complex

Comment: @Marat thank you, I already tried to do it but to approximate a function to the curves of the image I get function of 5th degree, also makes it dificult for the calculations

Comment: Maybe label a 100 and use interpolation then?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.